# Running a python app alongside the live interpereter

Tags: python, multithreading, pygame

I'm making a drawing program with python and pygame. I am trying to incorporate a script-fu thing in which the program opens a python live interpreter upon startup and allows the user to execute commands in the interpreter alongside the graphical interface.

My current strategy is to run the main loop inside its own thread, then have the application opened using a bash script that does 'python -i main.py'

Is this a safe/effective/ideal way of doing this? How can I use locks to ensure that commands coming in from the interpreter are executed between main loop iterations?

This is my first time using threads, so please explain to me like I am 7.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using a third party live interpreter?  Do you realize that pygame comes with one built in?  The documentation is [here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html).  This will eliminate all of your problems quite easily.

Comment: Is this the correct link? It took me to the events page of pygame... I didn't know pygame had an interpreter. That certainly sounds like something I could use :D

Comment: @hedgehogrider Yes, pygame does have an interperater, and that is the correct link.  Happy programming!

Answer (score 3):

The interpreter won't cooperate with locks you set (since it doesn't know about them). Thus, you cannot guarantee when the code entered by the user will execute.

Consider using the [`code` module](http://docs.python.org/library/code.html) to build your own interactive console (it's really easy!). Then you can do the locking every time you go to execute user input.